# naming objects from a list of names

Tags: python, arrays, variables, graphic

I am using graphics.py to create a simple UI.  I want to set up a number of Entry objects as fields.  Is there a way to loop through a list of field names and use them as variable names to create Entry objects?  Or is this the dreaded "dynamic variable" boogeyman that seems to be avoided at all costs?

Conceptually, I'd like to be able to write something like this:

```
from graphics import *
window = GraphWin("contact data", 200, 200)
x = 100
y = 10
field_names = ['name', 'address', 'phone']
field_text = ['Al', '123 4 Street', '555-666-7777']
for i in range(len(field_names)):
field_names[i] = Entry(Point(x, y + 30 * i), 15)
field_names[i].draw(window)
field_names[i].setText(field_text[i])
# don't know how to embed an image here to show the window
window.getMouse()
window.close()
```

to yield:

```
print(name)
Al
print(address)
123 4 Street
print(phone)
555-666-7777
```

but i get:

```
print(name)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\GoogleDrive\CMPT103\graphics\untitled-1.py", line 15, in 0
builtins.NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

Comment: It's unclear what is the expected and received output, please consider editing your question to add further information.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a dictionary or an array.

Comment: @mephy: i have added some detail to the code in the hopes that it clarifies what I'd like to do, if there's a way to do it, and what my attempts so far have yielded.

Comment: @MarkReed I have read that dictionaries are usually the answer given to people who want to create dynamic variables.  Is that what I'm trying to do above?  If so, how could i use inputted data or a pre-generated list as keys in a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
field_names[i].setText(field_text[i])
```

What are you trying to do?  Strings don't have a `setText` method.

Even if they did, however, you wouldn't be setting the variables you think you are. You would be changing the `field_names` array, so that the first element would no longer be `name` and would instead be the value of the `name` item.

What you want is a dictionary.  First, declare the dictionary at the top of the script:

```
values_dict = {}
```

And set entries in it like this:

```
values_dict[field_names[i]] = field_text[i]
```

after which you can access them like this:

```
print(values_dict['name'])
```